# how to change datetime format column that contains a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've a data frame contains a column (Start Shift) and it has different data types (Datetime/string), What i need is to change the datetime format to be time format only and keep the string without any change, i used the below code to solve this issue but i can't find a way to apply this change in the data frame as when i trying to load the data frame after this change i found nothing has been changed.

**The code that i used:-**

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Mahmoud.Bader\Desktop\FP Attendance V1.6 Apr 22.xlsx","Attendance").fillna("")

for i in df['Start Shift']:
    try:
        if i.isalpha():
            i
    except:
            i.strftime('%H:%M %p')
```

**The Data Frame is:-**

```
Department  Start Shift
Accommodation   Annual
Accommodation   OFF Day
Accommodation   2022-04-01 12:00:00
Accommodation   2022-04-01 09:00:00
Accommodation   2022-04-01 10:00:00
Complaints  OFF Day
Complaints  2022-04-29 07:00:00
Complaints  2022-04-29 08:00:00
Complaints  2022-04-30 07:00:00
Complaints  2022-04-30 08:00:00
```

[image]

**The Data Frame that i expected to found:-**

```
Department  Start Shift
Accommodation   Annual
Accommodation   OFF Day
Accommodation   12:00 PM
Accommodation   09:00 AM
Accommodation   10:00 AM
Complaints  OFF Day
Complaints  07:00 AM
Complaints  08:00 AM
Complaints  07:00 AM
Complaints  08:00 AM
```

Comment: Is it always the same format? `"{text} {%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}"`

Comment: yes, the datetime format is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cast the dates into [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first:

```
# cast column 'Start Shift' to datetime
df['Start Shift Formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Shift'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
# convert into requested time format
df['Start Shift Formatted'] = df['Start Shift Formatted'].dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
# overwrite old time format
df['Start Shift'] = df['Start Shift'].mask(df['Start Shift Formatted'].notna(), df['Start Shift Formatted'])
# drop column 'Start Shift Formatted' as it is no longer needed
df.drop('Start Shift Formatted', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Update**: This can be applied to multiple columns using the following function:

```
def format_time(x):
    x_temp = pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
    x_temp = x_temp.dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
    x = x.mask(x_temp.notna(), x_temp)
    
    return x

df.loc[:, ['Start Shift','End Shift','Login Time','Logout time']] = df[
    ['Start Shift','End Shift','Login Time','Logout time']
].apply(format_time)
```

Comment: great, the final code is the answer

Comment: i solved it by below code `for i in df[['Start Shift','End Shift','Login Time','Logout time']]:
    df['Formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(df[i], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
    # convert into requested time format
    df['Formatted'] = df['Formatted'].dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
    # overwrite old time format
    df[i] = df[i].mask(df['Formatted'].notna(), df['Formatted'])
    # drop column 'Start Shift Formatted' as it is no longer needed
    df.drop('Formatted', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Nice, I have updated my solution where you can find an alternative :)

Comment: may you share with me any contacting way such E-Mail to refer back to you if i wanted anything else in the future., it's really nice to meet you here

Comment: Sorry, I don't share private private information here on SOF. If you need help in the future, feel free to ask a new question and provide me with a link here in the comments.

Comment: Many Thanks for your support, Actually i've another small issue and need your help, so should i ask my question here or should i create a new post with new question?

Comment: Please ask a new question if it is unrelated to your initial question posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the changes to the column:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pandas

column = df['Start Shift']
for i in range(len(column)):
    if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', column[i]):
        column[i] = datetime.strptime(column[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M %p')
    else:
        column[i] = column[i]
```

You can also write this as a function and apply it to your column

```
def format_time(string):
    if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', string):
        string = datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%H:%M %p')
    return string
df['Start Shift'] = df['Start Shift'].apply(format_time)
```

This works for me:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Start Shift'])

df['Start Shift'] = ['Annual', 'OFF Day', '2022-04-01 12:00:00', '2022-04-01 09:00:00', '2022-04-01 10:00:00']

print(df.to_string(index = False))

df['Start Shift'] = df['Start Shift'].apply(format_time)

print(df.to_string(index = False))
```

Output:

```
        Start Shift
             Annual
            OFF Day
2022-04-01 12:00:00
2022-04-01 09:00:00
2022-04-01 10:00:00

Start Shift
     Annual
    OFF Day
   12:00 PM
   09:00 AM
   10:00 AM
```

Comment: how can apply this function to each row in that column.?

Comment: i want to mentioned that my code is working fine but i can't apply this change to appear in the data frame, the final view that i found like this  `Annual
12:00 PM
09:00 AM
10:00 AM
08:00 AM
14:00 PM
Annual
09:00 AM
14:00 PM
12:00 PM
08:00 AM
Annual
Casual`

Comment: try `dataframe['column'].apply(function)`

Comment: @MahmoudBadr I think I missunderstood your question I edited my answer maybe this is better.

Comment: can i take your email to discuss this case with you on google meet or zoom if it's suitable for you?

Comment: @MahmoudBadr is my code not working?

Comment: yes, its not working as you built your code based on fixed date (r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}') although I've a column (Start Shift) have different dates/times and strings so I've to iterate on every cell to test it, if it's string, keep it as the same, and if it's a datetime, so change the format to be time only

Comment: @MahmoudBadr As you can see in my latest edit. I tried it with you data

Comment: can we meet on Google meet please to clarify the issue in an easier way? (could you please share with me your google email)